# `native-base` .However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: react-native

Error: While trying to resolve module `native-base` from file `C:\Users\byambadorj\Desktop\LoginEx\src\LoginScreen.js`, the package `C:\Users\byambadorj\Desktop\LoginEx\node_modules\native-base\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\byambadorj\Desktop\LoginEx\node_modules\native-base\src\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist
C:\Users\byambadorj\Desktop\LoginEx\node_modules\native-base\src\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

- C:\Users\byambadorj\Desktop\LoginEx\node_modules\native-base\src\index\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\byambadorj\Desktop\LoginEx\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:311:17)......

> This is my package.json

```
{
      "name": "LoginEx",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint ."
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
        "native-base": "^3.2.2",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.66.4",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
        "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.16.7",
        "@babel/runtime": "7.16.7",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
        "eslint": "7.14.0",
        "jest": "26.6.3",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you just stop the metro and run again? If that doesn't work, uninstall the app and install it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stopping metro and restart it by clearing cache.

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Comment: try to clean build, close everything and rebuild. @famfamfam

Answer (score 0):

Try stop metro and restart it by clearing cache

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

if you are using mac it will not work. try this on mac

```
sudo npm start --reset-cache
```